# How to achieve row level versioning in redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, versioning, amazon-redshift

I am using AWS Redshift for performing analytical queries. The query does some computation and updates the value for a key. This result is exported to a queue system for asynchronous clients to consume. However, as queuing system do not ensure ordering, I need a mechanism to determine order. I need something like an "update_version" column, which gets incremented in each update operation. This is something analogous to [optimistic locking](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.html).

How do I achieve this in redshift?

One way is to use timestamp but it is not reliable as timestamp is fetched from individual nodes in the cluster and is prone to [clock skew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_skew).

I do not need global ordering.

Note: Please do not suggest to use an ordered queue as there are different challenges out of the scope of this question.

Comment: If two processes were simultaneously updating a key's value, why would one be more correct than the other? In other words, if your queue worker threw away any new messages older than the most recent processed one, what differenct would clock skew make?

Comment: Also, even though the value for a given data point may be spread across several nodes, only the clock on the worker node selected to run the update query would count. All the timestamp values across the various node stores for a given update would be identical.

Answer (score 1):

You could do one of the following:

- Run `UPDATE my _table SET update_version = update_version+1;`
- Run `INSERT INTO my_table SELECT *, update_version = N FROM my_table;`

The `UPDATE` is more disruptive to your table (existing data range becomes increasingly unsorted) but easier to query. The `INSERT` is less disruptive (new data is appended to an unsorted area, existing data is unaffected) but it's more difficult to query if you only need to find the current value.

If you want to use the `UPDATE` strategy but you care about history you should consider a `my_table_history` table that you write the current row values to *before* you perform the update.